# How to connect my web rails app with other plataform based apps?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i think my title is a little confusing but, what i'm thinking to do is:

I have my RoR website hosted on a ubuntu server with the postgres sql. I'm thinkin in a way to port the function of my website to a mobile app for example.

EX: i have a online chat website, so i want to create a native iOS app that can use the same functions and same database from my website in rails.

What i need to study first to learn how to connect my web-app to other apps in rails?
What i need to search for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a REST API to connect your mobile app with the web one.

Here you have a link that can be helpful, but if you search in google there is a lot of information related to this.

https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/building-a-restful-api-in-a-rails-application

Comment: Thank you so much, i've been lost about that so really thank you!! =D